# Formula cell is pulling xml style sheet value when cell has multiple styles in EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, stream, epplus

I don't know if anyone has encountered this issue before. Basically, I am reading a formula cell value. The original cell has two font styles `Calibri`, and `Arial`. In such cases, it somehow tries to preserve the style and value is read as an XML Style Sheet (example below).

In my case, I could care less about the style. Is there a way to ignore style while reading cells?

```
<r xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <t>XS-1000</t>
</r>
<r xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <rPr>
        <b />
        <i />
        <sz val="18" />
        <rFont val="Arial" />
        <family val="2" />
    </rPr>
    <t>i</t>
</r>
<r xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <rPr>
        <b />
        <sz val="18" />
        <rFont val="Arial" />
        <family val="2" />
    </rPr>
    <t>™ ANALYZERS</t>
</r>
```

Here is the code to read excel rows:

```
private List<string> ReadRow(ExcelRange cells, int row, int startColumn, int numberOfCols, bool skipEmptyCol = false)
{
    if (row < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid start line.", "startLine");

    if (startColumn < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid start column.", "startColumn");

    if (numberOfCols < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid number of columns.", "numberOfCols");

    var rowData = new List<string>();
    int currentColumn = startColumn;

    while ((startColumn + numberOfCols > currentColumn))
    {
        var cellValueString = "";
        var cellValue = (cells[row, currentColumn].Value ?? "").ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellValueString) && !skipEmptyCol) { break; }

        rowData.Add(cellValueString);
        currentColumn++;
    }

    return rowData;
}
```

This is the formula in the cell its reading value from:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE('XEC PDF'!A3, "HEMATOLOGY CONTROL FOR ","")," and ","/")
```

Comment: Please, post your code, how are you reading the cell

Comment: @Magnetron, posted my code. I found a way to get the root value from the string, which is to parse as xml by adding a root tag and get the root value in the constructor, but I would like a better solution if there is:
`if (rowData[2].Contains("<"))
{
     string myXML = "<root>" + rowData[2] + "</root>";
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);
     InstrumentName = doc.Root.Value;
}`

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem. What version of EPPlus are you using? Can you share the original file?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was because there were 2 different font styles in a cell ("TM" was superscript, everything else was normal). When ExcelWorkbook.Calculate() method is executed, it converts cell value with xml tags to preserve styles. In my case, I'm extracting values using formulas and those superscripts are only required to show on reports. So my solution is to clear those richText, put normal values back, and run Calculate(). In addition, I encountered another issue when reading from merged cell, it just blows up. So I added a solution to that below as well.

**You can also extract values from XML formatted text by adding  tags and parse to get the values (which you can add it to your public data member properties). I've posted the solution to the bottom.

```
        internal ImportFormulaSheetResponse ImportFormulaSheet(string formulaFilePath)
        {
            var impFormRes = new ImportFormulaSheetResponse();

            try
            {
                using (var workbookFormula = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(formulaFilePath)))
                using (var workbookOriginal = CreateExcelPackage(this.Stream))
                {
                    List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>();
                    List<string> formulaSheets = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var worksheet in workbookOriginal.Workbook.Worksheets)
                    {
                        List<int> parameterCols = new List<int> { 1, 2, 17 };

                        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                        foreach(int col in parameterCols)
                        {
                            for (int row = 14; row < rowCount; row++)
                            {
                                if (worksheet.Cells[row, col].IsRichText)
                                {
                                    //removing super/sub script formatting from RichText Cell property
                                    var celVal = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
                                    if (worksheet.Cells[row, col].Merge == true)
                                    {
                                        string range = GetMergedRange(worksheet, row, col);
                                        worksheet.Cells[range].Merge = false;
                                    }
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col].Clear();
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value = celVal;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var worksheet in workbookFormula.Workbook.Worksheets)
                    {
                        if (worksheet.Name.Contains("Formula"))
                        {
                            workbookOriginal.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet.Name, worksheet);
                            formulaSheets.Add(worksheet.Name);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sheetNames.Add(worksheet.Name);
                        }
                    }

                    //Calculate so the formula references have updated values
                    workbookOriginal.Workbook.Calculate();
                    workbookOriginal.Save();
                    this.Stream = workbookOriginal.Stream;

                    return impFormRes;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                impFormRes.Notifications.AddError(ex.Source, ex.Message);
                return impFormRes;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find the merged range a specific cell it belongs to
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>merged cell string</returns>
        internal string GetMergedRange(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int row, int col)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet.MergeCellsCollection mergedCells = worksheet.MergedCells;
            foreach (var merged in mergedCells)
            {
                ExcelRange range = worksheet.Cells[merged];
                ExcelCellAddress cell = new ExcelCellAddress(row, col);
                if (range.Start.Row <= cell.Row && range.Start.Column <= cell.Column)
                {
                    if (range.End.Row >= cell.Row && range.End.Column >= cell.Column)
                    {
                        return merged.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class ExcelImport
    {
        //workbook.Calculate() generates xml style tag around a cell with multiple styling
        //so add root tag to make it a proper xml document, parse and read root value
        if (rowData[2].Contains("<"))
        {
            string myXML = "<root>" + rowData[2] + "</root>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);
            InstrumentName = doc.Root.Value;
        }
    }
```